# Leaflet depending on button and insertUI not rendering

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, r-leaflet

I'm developing a Shiny App. I've a panel that should have the following behaviour: First, there's only a button. If this button is clicked, there's a plot and another button. If this other button is clicked, there's another plot and a map.

However, the map is never rendered, even if there's no problem with the plot.

Here is a reproducible example :

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)

new_map = function(){
  m <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
    addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
  return(m)
}

new_map_v2 = function(){
  m <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
    addMarkers(lng=100, lat=-100, popup="This map is good")
  return(m)
}


ui <- navbarPage("Shiny app",
                 tabPanel("Tab1",
                          uiOutput("some_button"),
                          div(id = "page_basic")
                 )
)


server = function(input, output, session) {
  
values <- reactiveValues(launched = FALSE, comp = FALSE)
  
  
output$some_button = renderUI(if(!values$launched){
  tag_alea = tags$div(fluidRow(column(width = 6, actionButton("clic_zero", "Click me"))))
  HTML(paste0(tag_alea))
} else {tag_base = tags$div(fluidRow(column(width = 6,
                                               actionButton("clic_one", "Another completely different button")))
)
HTML(paste0(tag_base))
})

observeEvent(input$clic_zero, {
  values$launched = TRUE})

observeEvent(input$clic_one,{
  values$comp = !values$comp})

observe({ if (values$comp & values$launched){
  page_first = tags$div(id = "page_no_comp",
                                         fluidRow(
                                           column(width = 6, plotOutput("plot")),
                                           column(width = 6,
                                                  box(width = NULL,
                                                      title = "Here should be the map",
                                                      leafletOutput("new_map")
                                                  )
                                                  )
                                           )
                                         )
  ui_page_first = paste(page_first)
  removeUI(selector = "#page_comp")
  insertUI(
    selector = "#page_basic",
    where = "afterEnd",
    ui = HTML(ui_page_first))
} else if (!values$comp & values$launched){
  page_second = tags$div(id = "page_comp",
                        fluidRow(
                          column(width = 6, plotOutput("plot2")),
                          column(width = 6,
                                 box(width = NULL,
                                     title = "No map below, that's normal"
                                 )
                          )
                        )
  )
  ui_page_second = paste(page_second)
  removeUI(selector = "#page_no_comp")
  insertUI(
    selector = "#page_basic",
    where = "afterEnd",
    ui = HTML(ui_page_second))
  }
  })

output$new_map <-  renderLeaflet({
  new_map()
})

output$plot <- renderPlot({
  plot(c(1,2,3,4))
})

output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
  hist(c(4,3,2,1))
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What is really interesting and what I don't understand at all is the following behaviour: If I plot two maps instead of one, there's no problem anymore. The following code works perfectly well, even if all I did was adding a map called new_map_v2.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)

new_map = function(){
  m <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
    addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
  return(m)
}

new_map_v2 = function(){
  m <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
    addMarkers(lng=100, lat=-100, popup="This map is good")
  return(m)
}


ui <- navbarPage("Shiny app",
                 tabPanel("Tab1",
                          uiOutput("some_button"),
                          leafletOutput("new_map_v2"),
                          div(id = "page_basic")
                 )
)


server = function(input, output, session) {
  
values <- reactiveValues(launched = FALSE, comp = FALSE)
  
  
output$some_button = renderUI(if(!values$launched){
  tag_alea = tags$div(fluidRow(column(width = 6, actionButton("clic_zero", "Click me"))))
  HTML(paste0(tag_alea))
} else {tag_base = tags$div(fluidRow(column(width = 6,
                                               actionButton("clic_one", "Another completely different button")))
)
HTML(paste0(tag_base))
})

observeEvent(input$clic_zero, {
  values$launched = TRUE})

observeEvent(input$clic_one,{
  values$comp = !values$comp})

observe({ if (values$comp & values$launched){
  page_first = tags$div(id = "page_no_comp",
                                         fluidRow(
                                           column(width = 6, plotOutput("plot")),
                                           column(width = 6,
                                                  box(width = NULL,
                                                      title = "Here should be the map",
                                                      leafletOutput("new_map")
                                                  )
                                                  )
                                           )
                                         )
  ui_page_first = paste(page_first)
  removeUI(selector = "#page_comp")
  insertUI(
    selector = "#page_basic",
    where = "afterEnd",
    ui = HTML(ui_page_first))
} else if (!values$comp & values$launched){
  page_second = tags$div(id = "page_comp",
                        fluidRow(
                          column(width = 6, plotOutput("plot2")),
                          column(width = 6,
                                 box(width = NULL,
                                     title = "No map below, that's normal"
                                 )
                          )
                        )
  )
  ui_page_second = paste(page_second)
  removeUI(selector = "#page_no_comp")
  insertUI(
    selector = "#page_basic",
    where = "afterEnd",
    ui = HTML(ui_page_second))
  }
  })

output$new_map <-  renderLeaflet({
  new_map()
})

output$new_map_v2 <-  renderLeaflet({
  new_map_v2()
})

output$plot <- renderPlot({
  plot(c(1,2,3,4))
})

output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
  hist(c(4,3,2,1))
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My real Shiny app is more complex, and I really need the map to be displayed in this panel, after the clicks on the buttons. A solution could have been, I guess, to always display the map and sometimes "hide" or "show" it depending on the button status. I don't want this, as then I might have some problems with the organization of the page.

Of course I've only one map in my App. I guess the problem is that the app would need at least one "real" leafletOutput in the UI not depending on some observe event? Maybe to initialize something?
In my app, I tried adding another map, and the problematic map is displayed only the second time I click on the button, so that's not really good.